# Adding Tag to ListBox.Items in WPF

Tags: wpf, tags, listviewitem

I have a List box and I am populating it like following

this.lisbox1.Items.Add("One");
this.lisbox1.Items.Add("Two");

This works fine...

but I want to add a tag to each of these items by using the Tag property of ListViewItem....
so when i try to access items using index and cast to ListViewItem then i get null...it seems that they all are just stings and not ListViewItem.

ListViewItem listViewItem = this.listbox1.Items[0] as ListViewItem....

So I want to know what is best way to add items to listbox so that i can use the tag property to store some extra information.

Comment: WPF is *not* WinForms, so you should *not* be writing your code as if it were. Please read the [Walkthrough: Getting Started with WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms752299(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN for more information.

Comment: @Sheridan, that link is now dead. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt149845.aspx

Comment: Thanks @David... good old Microsoft, breaking stuff as usual. Here is the original page: [Walkthrough: Getting Started with WPF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms752299(v=vs.100).aspx). Thanks for adding the other link too.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are trying to do, but you can feed ListViewItem with Tag to ListBox like this:

```
this.listbox.Items.Add(new ListBoxItem() { Content = "One", Tag = "Tag1" });
this.listbox.Items.Add(new ListBoxItem() { Content = "Two", Tag = "Tag2" });
this.listbox.Items.Add(new ListBoxItem() { Content = "Three", Tag = "Tag3" });
```